# Gatling - problem with users creation with rampUsers when other scenarios are working

Tags: performance, gatling, scala-gatling

I have spotted some strange behaviour of gatling.
I have 5 scenarios which have such "setup":

```
    scn[00-04].inject(constantUsersPerSec(simulationConfig.UsersPerSec) during
      (simulationConfig.maxDurationSeconds seconds).max(simulationConfig.maxDurationSeconds)).protocols(protocol),
```

UsersPerSec = ~0.8

maxDurationSeconds = 240

and additionaly one scenario with:

```
    scn05.inject(nothingFor(120 seconds), rampUsers(100) during(2 seconds))
      .protocols(protocol)
```

So whole load last 240 seconds and after 120 seconds additional load should be created during 2 seconds. What I have observed:

- after starting creation of additional 100 new "users", old "users" from first 5 scenarios did not execute requests / stay inactive some time (why?)
- amount of 100 "users" is not reached after start ( internally only one blocking request to soap service is sent during one action - it can take from 5 seconds to ~30seconds ), it stays on about level of 70 (dark blue line) but it should reach amount of 100 "users" (why?)
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're confusing injection profile for something that would drive virtual users lifespan.
Injection profiles only drive when users are injected/started.
Lifespan is driven by your scenarios, once a user reach the end of its scenario, it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have created another test-project with:

```
    scn00.inject(rampUsers(100) during(2 seconds))
      .protocols(protocol),
    scn01.inject(nothingFor(20 seconds),rampUsers(100) during(2 seconds))
      .protocols(protocol)
```

In those scenarios I had left only

```
    .feed(customFeeder)
    .pause(1 seconds)
    .exec(customAction("Action X")((testData) => {
      val y = testData.getConfig -- sometimes reads shared file during initialization
      Thread.sleep(20000)
    }))
```

and results looked:
[image]

why in this chart we can see that:

1. amount of 100 users was not reached? rampUsers(100) during (2 seconds)
2. in that point this scenario should ends ( it contains almost only Thread.sleep(20000) )
3. why: second scenario could reach amount of 100 users even if it differs only with nothingFor(20 seconds), additionaly: why this scenario did not start after 20seconds but 40 seconds?
4. why: second scenario was frozen for 60 seconds and started to finishing after first scenario was completed by all users?

why it did not looked more or less like this:
[image]

Comment: NEVER block the Gatling threads! Your Thread.sleep(20000) is destroying everything!

Comment: If you want your users to do a pause, use the dedicated `pause` component.

Comment: Probably it is an answer - I will check it tomorrow. 
One from five base scenarios has call to soap service. That request can be blocked for 10 to 60 seconds before response will be received. So for this time whole thread is blocked and therefore other actors which are handled by that thread are blocked and therefore they are waiting for execution after thread will be unblocked (second peak on image in my first post)

Comment: Is it possible to handle case of scenario with such blocking action? Eg.: run this scenario with separate threads for each user?

Comment: Gatling is not JMeter. Virtual users are not threads, they are messages. You musn't block Gatling threads. SOAP is usually just XML over HTTP and you should use Gatling HTTP support for this.